# Flutter video_player replaying video loaded from assets

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, video, video-player

I am trying using the video_player package to try and load, play, and then replay a video from assets. The video loads correctly and plays fine on the first run through. However when I try to replay the video using _controller.seekTo(Duration.zero) and _controller.play() it remains frozen on the last frame of the video and won't replay back.

This occurs only in iOS but not in Android where it behaves as expected. And it only occurs for videos loaded from assets. If I load a video from a url using VideoPlayerController.network it also behaves as expected.

Below is the class I modified from the video_player example.

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/video/MOV_GET_OUT_BED.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: _controller.value.initialized
              ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
          )
              : Container(),
        ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                await _controller.seekTo(Duration.zero);
                setState( () {
                  _controller.play();
                } );
              },
              child: Text("Restart video")
            ),
        ]
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To auto replay, add this to your initState() method.

```
_controller.setLooping(true);
```